# Send SMS from WP site when publishing scheduled post

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduling

I would like to use WordPress' built-in post scheduling function to send SMS reminders to people about stuff from a website. The purpose is to create a feature in a membership site where people can sign up for reminders about whatever, and I can schedule these reminders and have them send automatically via SMS and email. I want to do this using PHP mail.

I've written a function that uses the `transition_post_status` hook, as follows:

```
function visa_reminder( $old_status, $new_status, $post ) {
  if ( ($old_status != 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish')
&& 'reminder' == $post->post_type
) {

/* 
* Note: Reminder is the CPT I have created for this purpose
* In the custom post, you can input mobile number, carrier domain, etc.
*/ 

        $number = get_field('mobile_number');
        $carrier = get_field('carrier_domain');
        $to = $number .'@'. $carrier;
        $from = 'me@email.com';
        $subject = 'Your visa reminder';
        $message = get_field('text'); 
        $headers = "From: $from\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo $message;

  }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'visa_reminder', 10, 3 );
```

I am calling the function `visa_reminder($old_status, $new_status, $post);` in single-reminder.php.

I then create a Reminder post and schedule it for a few minutes in the future, just to test.

What's happening right now is that the SMS is being sent as soon as I hit the Schedule button. And when the scheduled post is actually published, nothing further happens, except when I view the actual post (not that seeing the post is important--no one is really meant to see it, it's just supposed to send the SMS) I get PHP errors saying that the variables I've called in the function are not defined. I thought these would be passed through by the function, so I don't really understand how to fix that.

I've tried several permutations of this function over the past couple of days and have also experimented with the hook `future_to_publish` with no better luck. I feel like I am close, but I have two main questions:

1. I don't understand exactly how I'm supposed to define the variables that are being passed to the function on the page. If it's incorrect for me to pass `$old_status, $new_status, $post`, then what should I be putting in the function in single-reminder.php?
2. Why is the SMS message being sent when I hit Schedule? I would guess it's because the post is transitioning from 'draft' to 'schedule'. But then why does it not send the message again when it transitions from 'schedule' to 'publish'?

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: side note: dont use any carriers email to sms gateway if you want reliability

Comment: OK, duly noted. Do you have a better recommendation for how I should go about this? I could use a professional service but I really wanted to try building this myself. I should point out that the SMS doesn't need to be precise to the minute. If it arrives on the right day, that's good enough.